# Rails: has_many and routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to create a student that has many awards

So I have something like this in routes.rb:

resources :students, has_many => [:awards]

And I think this should make my link like this if I want to see the awards for a student:

localhost:3000/students/1/awards

But I am getting a route not found error.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't define the has_many in your routes file, its defined in your model:

```
#routes.rb
resources :students do
  resources :awards
end
```

```
#student.rb
has_many :awards
```

When making nested routes, you form a block and nest the resources inside as above. You can also define additional routes:

```
#routes.rb
resources :students do
  resources :awards
  get 'foo' => 'controller#index' # maps to /students/foo
end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
resources :students, :has_many => :awards
```

or even better

```
resources :students do 
  resources :awards
end
```

also running 'rake routes' from terminal would have alerted you to your broken routes :)